# Code::Blocks 20.03 can't suddenly find -lglfw3 in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, compiling, opengl, code-blocks

I installed Code::Blocks in my Ubuntu 20.04 about a month ago and tested it with a GNU GCC Compiler. It could run a simple *"Hello Word"*-program. I didn't use CodeBlocks after that.

But now a month later it can't compile anything! even the same "Hello World" with the same compiler. Instead it claims *"-lglfw3 not found"*. I can't change compilers either since CodeBlocks *"Can't find compiler executable in your configured search path's for [COMPILER NAME]"*
I installed Geany and it can run *"Hello World"* just fine (Of course, I still need CodeBlocks for more complex programming).

Do you guys have any idea why my Code::Blocks might not work? There has been some system updates hasn't there? Any idea on how to possibly fix this?

Comment: Install the mentioned library by `sudo apt-get install libglfw3-dev` and then retry.

Comment: Already had the package. I even reinstalled and restarted the computer but to no avail.

Comment: Try to move old codeblocks configuration out-the-way by `mv ~/.config/codeblocks/ ~/.config/codeblocks-old/` and then restart CodeBlocks.

Comment: Okay that worked, thanks! But couldn't you have used the answer section?

Comment: It was a suggestion. Great it helped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As N0rbert in comments suggested, moving `~/.config/codeblocks` resolved the issue. Guess you could just remove that folder too. Seems to wipe the list of latest projects tough.